# How to add downloaded images url one by one to List<String>

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have a `List<String> profileName = ['k1','k2','k3','k4','k5',];` I want to download a profileName one by one then add it to `final downloadedImagesUrl = [];` by using `downloadedImagesUrl.add(snapshot.data!);` Like for example we want to download the *k1* from firebase storage then pass the downloaded url to `final downloadedImagesUrl = [];` then download the *k2* and pass the downloaded url to `final downloadedImagesUrl = [];` *step by step* and so on. How can I achieved something like this.

Code:

```
final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
List<String> profileName = ['k1','k2','k3','k4','k5',];
final downloadedImagesUrl = [];

FutureBuilder(
    future: storage.ref('usersProfile/$profileName').getDownloadURL(),
    builder: (context,snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done 
           &&snapshot.hasData) {

        //problem
        downloadedImagesUrl.add(snapshot.data!);

        return Image.network(snapshot.data!);
      }
      return Container();
    }),
```

The problem with this code is that the `downloadedImagesUrl.add(snapshot.data!);` is randomly added the downloaded images profileName url to `final downloadedImagesUrl = [];` and I don’t want that to happen.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need a simple function to do it, i haven't test you code implementation but i think you should do this way

```dart
Future<List<String>> getDownloaedImageUrls() async {
    List<String> profileNames = [
      'k1',
      'k2',
      'k3',
      'k4',
      'k5',
    ];
    List<String> downloadedImagesUrl = [];
    for (var profileName in profileNames) {
      String imageUrl =
          await storage.ref('usersProfile/$profileName').getDownloadURL();
      downloadedImagesUrl.add(imageUrl);
    }
    return downloadedImagesUrl;
  }
```

The use it on your futurebuilder

```dart
 FutureBuilder(
                future: getDownloaedImageUrls(),
                builder: (context,snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done 
                       &&snapshot.hasData) {
//since the function will also return the array of image url then we just use the first image url here
                    return Image.network(snapshot.data[0]!);
                  }
                  return Container();
                }),
```

Hope it helps